# How to allow use of camera in the flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I am making an application that processes photos that the user selects, and I would like to put a "Allow use of the camera" option, just like Skype, Facetime, which need user permission to use the camera and microphone. How can I do this, and what should I add to "pubspec.yaml"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the permission dialog to your app, you have to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

And then, for the camera, you need at least 3 dependencies inside your `pubspec.yaml` file:

[camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)
Provides tools to work with the cameras on the device.

[path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)
Finds the correct paths to store images.

[path](https://pub.dev/packages/path)
Creates paths that work on any platform.

For more information, go to the official docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera).